# @font-face not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, font-face

I am trying all this different ways:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: "cursivas";
        src: url(Freestyle.ttf) format("truetype");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "tabs";
        src: url(FrutigerLTStd-Bold.otf) format("truetype");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'topMenuFont';
        src: url('frutigerltstd-bold-webfont.eot');
        src: url('frutigerltstd-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('frutigerltstd-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('frutigerltstd-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('frutigerltstd-bold-webfont.svg#FrutigerLTStd65Bold') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    p.customfont { 
        font-family: "cursivas";

    }
    p.tabs{
        font-family:'tabs';color:#8e8e8e;
    }
    p.menu{
        font-family:'topMenuFont';
    }
    p{
    font-size:30px;
        color:#8e8e8e;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p class="customfont">FAMILIAS  <span style="color:blue">RESERVAS</span></p>
    <p class="tabs">FAMILIAS  <span style="color:blue">RESERVAS</span></p>
    <p class="menu">FAMILIAS <span style="color:blue">RESERVAS</span></p>
    <p>FAMILIAS <span style="color:blue">RESERVAS</span></p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Path's are OK because they all work in FF,

any idea what am i missing?

Comment: i see all as default font (arial, i guess)

Comment: you import EOT format for only frutigerltstd-bold-webfont font not for others like Freestyle etc . So, generate eot font for all fonts

Comment: But still is not working. That's why i am trying with different fonts -and settings-.

Answer (score 2):

Try the syntax described [here](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Got the link from fontsquirrel.com, they use it for all generated fonts. You can also take a look at the [Google Web Font](http://www.google.com/webfonts) generated [css](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Eater%20Caps) (it only shows the fonts for the browser you use)

And load it in an external css file, that also might solve some problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, IE 7 only supports EOT with @font-face, not TTF.

Comment: but i am also importing it, no?